# Parsing from Facebook's Graph API. Should be simple but

Tags: php, parsing, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents, json

Actually I have been tasked to create a simple site and this is my first effort to merge with the facebook Graph API.

Thing is, I want to connect to a group and fetch the feed messages (no pics, no names, just the messages). Simple right?

In my php code I have set the group url page which, through my program, leads to a page like this...

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "xxxx",
         "from": {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "id": "xxxx"
         },
         "message": "First Feed!",          <!-- This one I want to parse -->
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "xxx",
               "link": "xxx"
            },
         ],


etc etc
```

Problem comes when I try to parse the messages' "First feed!"
Here is my php code so far:

```
<?php
    $groupID = 'xxx';

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$groupID.'/feed?access_token=xxx';
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    echo '<a href='.$url.'>Check the fetched contents</a>';

    $limit = 25;
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($result -> message as $message)
    {
      if ($counter == $limit) {break;}
      echo $message;
      $counter++;
    }
%>
```

The main problem is that I get no results at all...

Despite being a very simple and plain variation, I also tried some other things I've found over the forums, such as: `<br>`
Using `$result -> {'message'}; <br>`
Using `$result['message']; <br>`
Using firstly `$result = $result -> data` and then `$result = $result -> message <br>`
Not using the foreach loop `<br>`

Also I've checked with the `print_r()` function and even at the `file_get_contents` stage I get no results... (I use the `<pre>` tags around the function).

So, what am I doing wrong??????

PS: I've set offline privileges for my access_token

Answer (score 0):

The right object path would be:

```
var_dump($result->data->message)
```

but you say file_get_contents get no result. is url file include allowed ? or do you get an error ?

what happens if you click your debug link ? is the content shown ? if yes it is not a problem with the api query or token.

Comment: I've written you some previous comments but I deleted them since I found the problem, but still can't solve it. So far the problem seems to be in the file_get_contents...

I use this script

and I get this... 

`<?php`
`$temp =` `file_get_contents('http://tierradecamposcyprus.com/tierra.php');`
`if ($temp == NULL)`
`{ echo 'nothing'; }`
`else `
`{ echo $temp; }`
`?>`
`
I always get "nothing".
The page has a simple "hi!" in it.

Comment: Since I've seen some online php debugging sites rejecting the file_get_contents function (and all the other "file" functions - which the site doesnt recognise either), is it possible that it might be disabled from the server for security reasons? Currently I'am using the Yahoo! Small Bussiness server... (Php 5.3.6)

Comment: sounds like safe_mode. check if you have the curl extension to grap the data.